# Que signifie « A resp. B » ?

Tags: abréviations, bibliographie

**What does the 'resp.' mean here?**

> STRAUSS (Laur.) resp. Franc. PETERSEN, *Diss. de potu coffi*. Giessen, 1666, in-4°.

**Context:** This is a [bibliographic entry](https://books.google.com/books?id=_oRhAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA171) concerning one of the first books to discuss coffee (plant, seeds, & drink) in Europe. Attribution for the entire genre seems to be a mess (*e.g.* one Huguenot from Lyons may have used the name of his apothecary cousin as a pseudonym while in exile *or* his cousin may have plagiarized and updated his earlier work without him) but here **the *Disputation on the Puissance of Coffee*** (reprinted at Frankfurt the same year as [*De Potu Coffi*](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_M3COYJdzZmkC/page/n5)) **seems to have been a medical school dissertation written by Franz Peters** (not Petersen) **with Lorenz Strauss as his faculty advisor**. Because of confusion over their roles, Strauss sometimes gets credited as the writer and even got a genus of coffee relatives (*Straussia*) named after him.

[Wiktionary mentions](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/resp.#French) *resp.* can mean 'respectivement' but that doesn't seem to be what it is in this entry. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This abbreviation appears multiple times in that book and other bibliographies, always under the form "*A resp. B*". **B** is a Doctorate in Medicine student and has published a *dissertatio* written under the supervision of **A**.

The usual word *resp.* abbreviates in French is ***resp***ectivement but would make no sense here.

Another possible word is ***resp***onsable or ***resp***onsabilité. That would make sense as **A** can be seen as the *responsable* of the student for his work.

A third option, my initial guess, would be the Latin ***resp***onsa, meaning "reply (to)". Many abbreviations present in these bibliographies are based on Latin words.

The fourth option is very close, and is the French ***resp***ondant, modern French *répondant* (the one who replies), and is more than likely the right term as it perfectly matches the context:

Furetière [Respondant](http://xn--furetire-60a.eu/index.php/non-classifie/1063858366-)

> s. m. Celuy qui soustient des Theses en quelque science que ce soit. Il a ainsi argumenté contre le Respondant. Les distinguo sont extremement favorables aux Respondants.

TLFi [Répondant](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9pondant)

> ♦ Vx. Celui qui soutient une thèse et doit répondre aux objections. L'argumentant et le répondant. (Dict. XIXe et XXe s.).

Académie 8e édition [Répondant](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/r%C3%A9pondant) :

> Celui, celle qui répond. Il s'est dit spécialement de Celui qui subit un examen public, qui soutient une thèse. Le président et le répondant. Ce répondant a fort bien soutenu son examen, sa thèse.

This is confirmed too by looking to a German reference to this very same document:

> 656 Strauss, Laurentius [Praes.] u. Franz Peters (Frankf. a. M.) [Resp.]
>   Disputatio physico-medica de potu coffi.

Here Strauss is presiding (Latin *[praesidens](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/praesidens)*) and Peters(en) is responding (Latin *[respondens](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/respondens)*).

Comment: Thanks for your time. =) That would be incorrect but, given the *oreille de cochon* of attribution surrounding this issue, hardly surprising. Do you have some support or examples from elsewhere that suggest that's the most likely meaning here?

Comment: No... I think you must be right. [This German .pdf](http://geb.uni-giessen.de/geb/volltexte/2006/3891/pdf/SchuelingHermann-Diss_1650_1700.pdf) describes the same book as "Strauss, Laurentius [Praes.] u. Franz Peters (Frankf. a. M.) [Resp.] Disputatio physico-medica de potu coffi. Giessae Hass. April 1666: Karger. (2), 17 S. 4° placidae disquisitioni." I know *praes.* is short for some Latin version of "preside" so the *resp.* should be Latin for some version of "response", in reference to the student providing the dissertation.

Comment: If you have time to come back and clean up your answer (ideally with a ref and description of *praes.* and *resp.* but in any case to show that *responsa* seems to have been the right answer, if not exactly French), I'd be happy to go ahead and tick it correct.

Answer (score 3):

Given the sentence:

> a medical school dissertation written by Franz Peters (not Petersen) with Lorenz Strauss as his faculty advisor.

I suggest: ***resp***onsable ("responsible")

Comment: Thanks for your time. =) That would fit the context but do you have any sources or examples from elsewhere that suggest that is what's being said here?

Comment: @lly: Have a look at [here](https://meltingmots.com/abreviations/responsable/4215)